# Unity - writing gameObjects into variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2d array storing gameObjects and a method for updating logic.
Here is the 1st code:

```
public void UpdatePlayerPosition(Vector3 posStart, Vector3 posEnd)
    {
        
        _levelItems[(int)posEnd.x, (int)posEnd.z] = _levelItems[(int)posStart.x, (int)posStart.z];
        _levelItems[(int)posStart.x, (int)posStart.z] = null;

    }
```

Here is the 2nd code

```
public void UpdatePlayerPosition(Vector3 posStart, Vector3 posEnd)
    {
        var placeStart = _levelItems[(int)posStart.x, (int)posStart.z];
        var placeEnd = _levelItems[(int)posEnd.x, (int)posEnd.z];

        placeEnd = placeStart;
        placeStart = null;

    }
```

The 1st code is working fine however I would like it to be more readable like the 2nd that is not working. I know about the vars refs and value stuff so I know why it is not working properly. Is there any way to make it work properly and look good ? The best I can do is

```
public void UpdatePlayerPosition(Vector3 posStart, Vector3 posEnd)
    {
        var placeStart = _levelItems[(int)posStart.x, (int)posStart.z];
        var placeEnd = _levelItems[(int)posEnd.x, (int)posEnd.z];

       _levelItems[(int)posEnd.x, (int)posEnd.z] = placeStart;
        _levelItems[(int)posStart.x, (int)posStart.z] = null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd code will not work because you are just assigning the value of `_levelItems[(int)posStart.x, (int)posStart.z]` and `_levelItems[(int)posEnd.x, (int)posEnd.z]` to `placeStart` and `placeEnd` respectively. Then you just change the value of the later 2 variables and not the array. You must change the value to the array variables directly to change them.

In my opinion, a more clean code will be like this:

```
public void UpdatePlayerPosition(Vector3 posStart, Vector3 posEnd)
{
    int xStart = (int)posStart.x;
    int zStart = (int)posStart.z;
    int xEnd = (int)posEnd.x;
    int zEnd = (int)posEnd.z;

    _levelItems[xStart, zStart] = null;
    _levelItems[xEnd, zEnd] = placeStart;
}
```